# Does a open source DB exist that exposes SQL DB as a web service?

Tags: sql-server, web-services

Do any of the existing open source databases have the ability to expose a database as a web service on a server port?    I'm looking for something like Microsoft SQL Servers ability to expose a wsdl web service URL .

If not, I guess i will use SQL Server Developer Edition...

Comment: Expose the database as a set of entities (the tables)? Allow searches and updates? Expose the database for adminsitration, like phpMyAdmin? Expose a service that acceps arbitrary SQL? Expose a set of defined WS methods, like SQL Server HTTP endpoints?

Comment: I think he wants something similar to Amazon SimpleDB http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: How many tables & rows are there in your db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CouchDb is built around HTTP](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API), with all actions being http methods.  This makes the database easy to access from a variety of platforms and languages.

However, you can create a web server for any databases, for the given app with varying degrees of flexibility.

Comment: I agree, couch is tailor made for this scenario.

Comment: I liked that answer but alas, I played around with it a little and it was tough to figure out.   I've given up and chosen instead to use a bound SQL connection in Visual Studio (the usual method) and now I use the MVC design pattern and "database entity binding" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with any database connected to a [JBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Business_Integration) like [openEsb](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/) if you use a binding component like [DatabaseBC](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=DatabaseBC)

this is a good [screencast](http://webcast-west.sun.com/interactive/09B12452/index.html) on how generating a WSDL from an SQL file ... for more details you can look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=UsingDatabaseBindingComponent) ...